# Getting all the Contents of an <a> tag with a class of .profile-link and print it out

Tags: jquery, class

need help on a jquery code that gets all the content of all the  tag with a class of .profile-link ?? to print out because their is a bunch of codes that I don't need and I just need all the contents from the specific  tag

Comment: are you looking for the content between the `<a></a>` tags? or the attributes of the `<a>` tag like `href` `target`, `title`, etc?

Answer (score 1):

Try `$('.profile-link').html();` if you need the link's contents for reuse (non-escaped HTML, treated as HTML).

`$('.profile-link').text();` if you are just grabbing a string.

Answer (score 1):

If you want all the content of the a tag with a class.

```
$('a.profile-link').map(function() {
    return $(this).text();  // use .html() if you want the html content.
}).get().join("\n"); // joined by newline, you could change to other else.
```